Выровнять блоки по левому краю, центру и правому краю


.g {
  display:flex;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background: green;
}
.l {
  height:100%;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background: red;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.r {
  height:100%;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background: blue;
}
<div class='g'>
  <div class='l'>L</div>
  <div class='r'>R</div>
</div>





.g {
  display:flex;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background: green;
}
.l {
  height:100%;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background: red;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.r {
  height:100%;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background: blue;
}

.C {
  height:100%;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.l {
   margin:unset;
}
<div class='g'>
  <div class='l'>L</div>
  <div class='C'>C</div>
  <div class='r'>R</div>
</div>



Когда в блоке появляется блок по центру, необходимо фиксить левый
.l {
   margin:unset;
}

Иначе центральный блок не будет расположен по центру.
Вопрос в том, возможно ли универсально сделать, чтобы лишний раз не пришлось фиксить левый блок.
Изначально на левом блоке
margin-right:auto;

Иначе правый блок не прижать к правому краю...

Можете убрать марджины для блоков и использовать justify-content: space-between для g

Не то, данное свойство равномерно все элементы цетрирует по горизонтали. , Необходимо чтобы левый и правый блок были прижаты по краям.

Вы говорите о space-around, а не space-between, пример

Работает, немного не то. К сожалению необходимо было по два блока с лева и права делать, в таком случаи margin-right:auto; применялся ко второму. То есть изначально 4 блока, 2 справа и с лева. Затем добавляем между ними блок который необходимо выровнять по центру между двумя с права и двумя с лева

Какую ситуацию я не предусмотрел?


.g {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.l {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
}

.r {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.C {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
}

.g:not(:has(.C)) .l+.l {
  margin-right: auto;
}
<div class='g'>
  <div class='l'>L</div>
  <div class='C'>C</div>
  <div class='r'>R</div>
</div>

<div class='g'>
  <div class='l'>L</div>

  <div class='r'>R</div>
</div>

<div class='g'>
  <div class='l'>L</div>
  <div class='l'>L</div>
  <div class='C'>C</div>
  <div class='r'>R</div>
  <div class='r'>R</div>
</div>

<div class='g'>
  <div class='l'>L</div>
  <div class='l'>L</div>

  <div class='r'>R</div>
  <div class='r'>R</div>
</div>



